# Is there a way to restrict branch creation pattern in github?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I have a main branch and if someone wants to create new branch then it must start with `feature/*`, `bugfix/*`, `release/*`.

I tried using branch protection rules, but I couldn't find any settings that prevent the creation of these branches which do not match the pattern.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71281569/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+restrict+branch

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to protect some central repo you can use pre-commit hooks (see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)) for such task. As you can see from here hooks can be client- and server-side. They are in git for a long time and were used in many such situations e.g. in gerrit toolkit. So probably it will not be a big problem to implement some filter based on the name for such hooks. As I know they can be implemented as shell scripts.

So ok, for Github one can use [Rulesets feature](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets). Take a look at it.

Comment: At Github one cannot setup server-side hook, only web-hooks.

Comment: At least there are [Rulesets](https://github.com/user/repo/settings/rules)

Comment: With rules one can protect a branch but cannot have a negative rules. I.e. one can forbid to create branch `main` but cannot forbid everything except for some names.

Comment: As I can see there is deny creation rule with target All possible

Comment: Found the required option in Metadata restrictions section of ruleset.

Answer (score 1):

you can have an alias to run a shell scrip that will create branch with specific pattern as default and if somebody tries to create a branch with customized name rather than the default branch pattern then delete the branch with a warning message.

sample snippet for the logic:

```
    local branch_name=$1
    local allowed_patterns=("feature/" "bugfix/" "release/")
    local valid=0
    for patterns in "${allowed_patterns[@]}"; do
        if [[ $branch_name == "$patterns"* ]]; then
            valid=1  # Valid branch name
        fi
    done
    #deleting branch if it is not valid pattern
     if [[ $valid!=1 ]];then
        git branch -D $branch_name
        echo "warning message you want to set"
     fi
```